# Application Style CSS3/JQM Bar

Tags: asp.net, css, web-applications, jquery-mobile

For the past couple of days I've been pondering and attempting to create a well-scaling and clean bit of code for a mobile version of a web platform I'm working on.

I'm trying to achieve (using CSS3 preferably, but I'm not adverse to JQuery Mobile) the iOS-style application footer bar with icons/images which scale properly when viewed on a mobile (landscape/portrait) and on a desktop.

If you've never seen the application bar, here's a link: http://tinyurl.com/98ftqrr

I've knocked together a quick picture of what I'm trying to achieve on the mobile platforms (apologies for my MSPaint skills):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/mobilei.png/

The squares inside the tiles on the app bar represent icons (currently there's a plan for 3-4 of these)

Here's an image I drew up representing this from the context of a desktop/tablet

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/desktopog.png/

Now, I know that this it's fairly easy to add some styling to a footer, but that's not the issue I can't seem to get around in my head. Firstly, having the navigation icons in the bar look crisp in all resolutions is proving a bit of a challenge (mainly because I can't seem to figure out how to do this properly); also, obtaining the *exact* iOS look - is proving to be difficult.

Any help anyone is willing to give on this will be much appreciated, I understand the question may seem a little basic and abstract.

Thanks.

Comment: your question sure is abstract.... you want an iOS-style navbar, which is on the side of the display? Please be less abstract ;-)

Comment: Apologies - I should've specified where I want it to appear is irrelevant. I just want to replicate it so that the icons I place on it scale properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an CSS cross devices iOS-style navbar (bottom only), use my [bartender CSS plugin](https://github.com/frequent/bartender).

To make this a sidebar, you will have to be creative... I gave it a few tries, but this is not easy just considering positioning of this element (there's much more). Your best chance might be the [popup sidepanel](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/popup-panels.html#&ui-state=dialog), which you'd have to config to hold the toolbar.

Comment: Excellent, great suggestion with the side panel too. Much appreciated.